# How to initialize the ejabberd module inside other module

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I Need to connect the AWS elastic search from ejabberd.So, I found the below module to connect after started to integrate as per instruction given in the module i get some errror

Call this function : elasticsearch:index(<<"my_index">>, <<"_doc">>, <<"id">>, #{<<"my_key">> => <<"my_value">>})

Link : https://github.com/Qualia91/elasticsearch-erlang

Erro`{{noproc,{gen_server,call,[elasticsearch_workers,{checkout,#Ref<0.623895423.2148532225.144069>,true}, 5000]}},`

Answer (score 1):

I applied this patch to ejabberd git, started it interactively using "make relive", and in the console I tried this:

```
elasticsearch:index(<<"my_index">>, <<"_doc">>, <<"id">>, #{<<"my_key">> => <<"my_value">>}).

{error,{failed_connect,[{to_address,{"localhost",9200}},
                        {inet,[inet],econnrefused}]}}
```

Patch:

```
diff --git a/rebar.config b/rebar.config
index 746f62fb7..bb4829a07 100644
--- a/rebar.config
+++ b/rebar.config
@@ -20,6 +20,7 @@
 
 {deps, [{base64url, ".*", {git, "https://github.com/dvv/base64url", {tag, "1.0.1"}}},
         {cache_tab, ".*", {git, "https://github.com/processone/cache_tab", {tag, "1.0.30"}}},
+        {elasticsearch, ".*", {git, "https://github.com/Qualia91/elasticsearch-erlang", {branch, "master"}}},
         {eimp, ".*", {git, "https://github.com/processone/eimp", {tag, "1.0.22"}}},
         {if_var_true, tools,
          {ejabberd_po, ".*", {git, "https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-po", {branch, "main"}}}},
diff --git a/rel/relive.config b/rel/relive.config
index 7e3901fd4..301342ca6 100644
--- a/rel/relive.config
+++ b/rel/relive.config
@@ -1,3 +1,16 @@
 [{mnesia, [{dir, "_build/relive/database"}]},
+ {elasticsearch, [
+    {pools, [
+        {elasticsearch_workers, [
+            {size,         10},
+            {max_overflow, 20}
+        ], [
+            {worker_impl,  elasticsearch_worker},
+            {url,          "localhost"},
+            {port,         9200},
+            {http_options, []}
+        ]}
+    ]}
+ ]},
  {ejabberd, [{config, "_build/relive/conf/ejabberd.yml"},
              {log_path, "_build/relive/logs/ejabberd.log"}]}].
diff --git a/src/ejabberd.app.src.script b/src/ejabberd.app.src.script
index 4c8745146..1f83289ef 100644
--- a/src/ejabberd.app.src.script
+++ b/src/ejabberd.app.src.script
@@ -19,6 +19,7 @@ Vars = case file:consult(filename:join([filename:dirname(SCRIPT), "..", "vars.co
     [compiler, inets, mnesia, os_mon,
      cache_tab,
      eimp,
+     elasticsearch,
      fast_tls,
      fast_xml,
      fast_yaml,
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I checked the point you provided above, but I couldn't find the relive.config, ejabberd.app.src.script files in my ejabberd 20.07 version. It appears that only the latest version of ejabberd has the relive.config file. Could you please explain how to address this issue in ejabberd 20.07?

Comment: Could you please help me to resolve the above issue

Comment: Create a new file with content [{elasticsearch, [...]}].
Then edit ejabberdctl.cfg and set the path to that file like this:

ERL_OPTIONS="-config /home/ejabberd/whatever/conf/elastic.config"